# Applying mask to 40 Landsat images on ENVI?

Tags: landsat, envi, masking

I'm new to ENVI and am working on a time series for a section of the Santa Barbara Channel.

I have a mask I made from the ROI tool, but was wondering if there is an efficient way to mask all 40 of my images instead of doing it manually image by image?

Also, is there a particular term I should look for when searching for information on bulk processing on ENVI?

I'll be using L4-5 and L7, if that means anything.

Comment: Do you have access to ArcGIS or just ENVI?